# AlertDialog in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to show a alertdialog but i keep getting this error

```
01-24 21:52:45.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31119): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
01-24 21:52:45.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31119): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
01-24 21:52:45.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31119):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
01-24 21:52:45.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31119):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:100)
01-24 21:52:45.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31119):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:96)
01-24 21:52:45.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31119):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:891)
```

It is pointing to this line

```
 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch (id) {
  case 1:
      isGameRunning = false;
      gameStarted = false;
      mEngine.stop();
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setTitle("How To Play");
      builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);



      final AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); //this line

      builder.setPositiveButton("Thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            alert.dismiss();
            isGameRunning = true;
            mEngine.start();
            gameStarted = true;

        }
        });
      return alert;
  default:
      return null;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like, for some reason, the method `onCreateDialog` is called from the UpdateThread of AndEngine (While it should be called from the UI Thread).

Remember that when you show a dialog, you call `showDialog(int id)` rather than `onCreateDialog(int id)`. After you call `showDialog`, Android will call `onCreateDialog` on the UI thread when possible.

In fact, I looked in [showDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int%29) info now and it is deprecated, it looks like there is a whole new way of creating dialogs. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Answer (score 6):

Call showDialog from the UIThread.

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyActivity.this.showDialog(MY_DIALOG_ID);
    }
});
```

Oh and NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO, NO:

```
case 1:
```

Comment: From which method should i call this runOnUiThread()?? I want to take user name as input. I'm using SimpleBaseGameActivity. I tried running it from onCreateScene() before return; but my UI gets distort.

Comment: I mean i call it from an External class with context of SimpleBaseGameActivity but in output i'm just getting some part of my actual background image and it is Fluctuating and other part is black.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch (id) {
  case 1:
      isGameRunning = false;
      gameStarted = false;
      mEngine.stop();
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
       builder.setTitle("How To Play")
              .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
              .setPositiveButton("Thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            isGameRunning = true;
            mEngine.start();
            gameStarted = true;

        }
        });
      return builder.create();
  default:
      return null;
  }       
}
```