# Android (w Andengine), Creating a dialog Box. Getting User data from Seek Bar. Saving it to Shared Preferences

Tags: android, andengine

Basically I'm developing a game and wish to create a dialog box when user click/touches two texts (MFX and SFX Volumes). I don't know whether it can be made with Andengine, but anyways I tried making it after trying to understand Google Developer's Guide for Alert Dialog, SeekBar etc. It is presented below.

---

Earlier I was facing a issue:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1878): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

That's why I made it to run on update thread but no luck, he error still persits. I have very less experience working on this aspect of android. Sorry if it is too elementary.

---

```
private void createDialog(final int pid) {
    rM.engine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            SeekBar sb = new SeekBar(activity);
            final SharedPreferences volumePref = activity.getSharedPreferences(pid + "", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = volumePref.edit();
            sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                int volume = volumePref.getInt(pid + "", 100);// concatenation for conversion of int to string, a short method i like

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                    switch (pid) {
                        case MENU_MFX://These are id's which denote which volume we want to change
                        case MENU_SFX:
                            editor.putFloat(pid + "", volume);
                            editor.commit();
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                    volume = arg1;
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    rM.setMfxVolume(volumePref.getFloat(MENU_MFX + "", 1f));//These methods change volume, these work fine.
                    rM.setSfxVolume(volumePref.getFloat(MENU_SFX + "", 1f));
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known that sometimes running on update thread creates problems. So it should be done as:

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyActivity.this.showDialog(MY_DIALOG_ID);
    }
});
```

as told by @Nicolas [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10048827/1835779).